# While publishing asp.net application add_data folder is missing in visual studio 2015.How can i get?

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I am working in Visual studio 2015.App_data folder is missing while publishing the project.So I am getting an error like

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>  
    <system.web>
        <customErrors  mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Open App_Data folder in Solution Explorer, for each file inside app_data set property "Build Action" to "Content" . Rebuild solution . publish .

I think this will work .

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check your setting when you publish app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have unchecked the option Exclude files from app_data,but still not getting app_data in published folder

Comment: You can always publish only 'App_Data', click right on it > Publish.

Comment: I am gettin a message like-File App_Data/PublishProfiles/EHRMS.pubxml was ignored as it matches the set of extensions to skip when selectively publishing.